# How can I get the value of the selected filter in Magento 1.9 Grid and use it in another filter?

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, invoice, filter

I need to get the filter value for a column and use it to further filter the results of another column, for example, country and states. How can I do this?

```
_prepareCollection:


        $collection->getSelect()->join( 
        // Table
        'sales_flat_order_address',
        // Where Claus
        'main_table.order_id=sales_flat_order_address.parent_id', 
        // Field
        array( 'company', 'country_id' , 'region')
    );


 protected function _prepareColumns():



$this->addColumn('region', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Region'),
            'index' => 'region',
            'filter_index' => 'sales_flat_order_address.region',
            'type'      => 'options',
            'options'      => $this->getAllRegions('country_id'),
             //'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_regionAddressFilter("country_id")')

        ));
```

and this is where I want to use the country code to filter regions in the region dropdown:

```
   protected function getAllRegions($column){
        $regions = array();
        $countryCode =  $this->getColumn($column)->getFilter()->getValue();
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('directory/region_collection')->load()->toOptionArray();
        foreach ($collection as $region) {
            $regions[$region['value']] = $region['label'];
        }
        return $regions;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there..

But you need to pass the `$countryCode` in a region collection to  get the exact result.

Like follows.

```
$regionCollection = Mage::getModel('directory/region_api')->items($countryCode);
return $regionCollection;
```

Comment: Thanks, but the `$this->getColumn($column)->getFilter()->getValue();` returns null. How can I get the selected country code?

Comment: $column returns the particular Column's ID. So You need to pass the <country_column_id> into this as statically. $this->getColumn(<$country_coulmn_id>)->getFilter()->getValue();